# How can I override the member of (->) operator of a base class

Tags: c++, qt, inheritance, overloading, operator-keyword

Background: I have Qt generated UI classes with no common ancestor. I am subclassing a  class (say, "Door") that uses one of these UI classes, and the derived class ("OakDoor") will use a different UI class, although much of the UI elements will have the same name.

Until now I have been hiding the base UI class (i.e the derivied class uses a UI class of different type but the same name) but now need to rely on inheritance to handle cases where the base class does work on the UI classes; hiding doesn't work in this case.

I have already asked about a way to do this using inheritance and got pointed in the direction of using composition. So I am trying to find an efficient way to do this without having to define an access function for every UI element. It's not really composition but I thought it was getting me close for little effort.

```
class form_container 
{
public:
  form_container(){};
  form_container(Ui_A_Form * form){_form = form;}
  ~form_container(){ delete _form; }  
  Ui_A_Form *_form;
  Ui_A_Form & operator->()
  {
    return *_form;
  }
};
```

the idea was then to have Door use this class and OakDoor a subclass of it:

```
class B_form_container : public form_container
{
public:
  B_form_container(Ui_B_Form * form){_form=form;}
  ~B_form_container(){delete _form;}  
  Ui_B_Form  *_form;
  Ui_B_Form & operator->()
  {
    return *_form;
  }
};
```

So I'm really just shifting the hiding. Anyway the problem seems to be with my overloading of the operator ->().
In my Door class, I have
`form_container *_myform`;
which is constructed thusly:

```
_myform = new form_container(new A_Form());
```

But it won't compile when I try to access anything in an A_Form, for instance the Qt SetupUI function:

_myform->setupUi(_a_widget);

I'm obviously doing something wrong. Would appreciate any help out there - many thanks! (I can see problems when the subclass tries to delete _form in the base class but I'll sort that out later)

Edit: OK this is compiling now (many thanks to @(R Sahu)), but I am not seeing the overloading that I expect. e.g:

```
class base_class()
{
   form_container *_myform;
};

class derived_class(): public base_class()
{
 //inherit _myform;
};

//(constructor for derived class)
derived_class()::derived_class()
{
  _myform = new B_form_container(new B_form());
  (*_myform)->setupUI(new QWidget());  // tries to setupUi on an A_form
}
```

This is calling form_container::operator->(), presumably because it isn't virtual. If I make it virtual in the base class form_container, the derived class B_form_container complains about the function only differing by return type.
Is there a way around this? 
Can I do something like this for instance:

```
class base : public A_form
{
 virtual base * operator->()
 {
    // not sure how to return ->() operator of A_form
    return A_form::operator->(); // ???
 }
};

class derived : public base, public B_form
{
 virtual base *operator->()
 {
   return B_form::operator->(); // again??? 
 }
} ;
```

Another edit: I don't think what I am trying to do is possible anymore. If you can correct me, please do. In the meantime I'm off to write something to process moc output and create classes with access functions which I *can* override.

Comment: Please provide a [Minimal, Complete, Verifiable Example](http://www.stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: It seems the more you try, the less it make sense... If `derived` derives from `base` then it indirectly derives from `A_form`. Thus is derived a `A_form` or a `B_form`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As I eventually realised above, this isn't possible. The operator ->() has to return the type upon which it is acting, and for that reason it can't be used as a virtual function.

Comment: A 'real' virtual function wouldn't work for this either. Those are required to have the same signatures too. You could, of course, give both `UI_?_Form` classes a common base with relevant virtual functions, and access them polymorphically via references/pointers to that base (thus preserving the signature).

Comment: that's exactly what I did. I ended up writing a small utility to take a .ui file and automatically write a base class with virtual functions. I call this as a build step when the .ui file is compiled so once it's set up, it's pretty handy.

Comment: Cool! Yep, polymorphism is really cool. Combined with templates, I'm not sure any other language would give me this much ability to create a complex spaghetti of template types _but_ give them all a common base interface. On 2nd thoughts, maybe I shouldn't have this much power. :D

Comment: It is not really fair to mark your own answer as the answer... even more that it is not really a solution.

Comment: its perfectly OK to answer your own question, and in this case the solution is that it isn't possible to do what I was looking for, and in the comments below I explained my workaround.

Answer (score 4):

```
_myform = new form_container(new A_Form());
_myform->setupUi(_a_widget);
```

is not the right syntax to use to access the `operator->()` function. With that syntax, the compiler expects a member function `setupUi()` in the class `form_container`. The right syntax is:

```
_myform = new form_container(new A_Form());
(*_myform)->setupUi(_a_widget);
// This translates to:
// Invoke the operator->() function on (*_myform)
// Use the return value of the function and call `setupUi()` on the returned pointer.
```

or

```
_myform = form_container(new A_Form());
_myform->setupUi(_a_widget);
```

Also, the function needs to return a pointer, not a reference.

```
Ui_B_Form* operator->()
{
  return _form;
}
```

Comment: Thanks for clearing up the reference thing, that is what I had originally. It does compile if I use your first correction (_myform is a form_container*). Can you explain why I need to dereference _myform in order to use the operator?

Comment: Sorry I've got to un-answer this. It turns out that although this compiles, I'm not getting the behaviour I expected. see edits above